# My PointerClick function gets fired twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an OnPointerClick() function that sometimes gets fired twice if I keep clicking on multiple buttons at a stretch, even though I have pressed this button only once. This is happening in the new Input UI System. How do I stop this from happening?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ClickableButtons : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData) {
        
       Debug.Log("Clicked"); //Called twice most of the time when button is pressed once
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's try to solve the problem caused by 2 clicks, before the causes of 2 clicks. Because the information you provide is not enough.

```
public class ClickableButtons : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    private static readonly object ClickLock = new object();

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        lock (ClickLock)
        {
            Debug.Log("Clicked"); //Called twice most of the time when button is pressed once
        }
    }
}
```

If you put the actions to be performed after the click in the "lock" statement, it will prevent the actions from being done at the same time.

```
public class ClickableButtons : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    private static readonly object ClickLock = new object();
    private bool clicked = false;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (clicked) return;

        lock (ClickLock)
        {
            clicked = true;

            Debug.Log("Clicked"); //Called twice most of the time when button is pressed once
            clicked = true;
        }

        clicked = false;
    }
}
```

You can try to control it with an "if" statement.
But what I'm wondering is why don't you use the button's onclick event?

https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

Comment: That's a neat workaround but I would rather focus on why the method is called twice in the first place -> most probably because the callback was added twice for some reason ..